# What is a 'manual' mock called?

Tags: java, mocking

if I do not use a mock framework to create a mock, but write my own mock which inherits the to be mocked class, and overwrites the specific method that I want to mock.
What is this called? Dummy? Fake? Stub

ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those kind of objects are still "mock" objects.

From Wikipedia, on the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) of a mock object:

> In object-oriented programming, mock objects are simulated objects
>   that mimic the behavior of real objects in controlled ways

And this is exactly what mock objects do, be them generated by a mocking framework or manually implemented in the unit tests